# Проблема в реализации добавления элемента в односвязный список

Tags: c++

**Проблема:** После добавления элемента на определённую позицию, все следующие элементы затираются, при это сам элемент также не добавляется.

***(прим: для ввода элементов вида 1 2 3 4 5 6, при попытке вставить элемент 5 на позицию 1, программа выдаст 1 -1)***

**Реализация односвязного списка:**

```
struct Node{
int data;
Node *nextAddress;
};

class List{

private:
    Node *headList;
    Node *lastList;

public:

    List(){
        headList = nullptr;
        lastList = nullptr;
    }
```

**Реализация метода добавления нового элемента на соответствующую позицию:**

```
void addAfter(int x, int position){
    Node *previous = this -> headList;
    for (int i = 0; i < position - 1; i ++){
        previous = previous -> nextAddress;
    }
    Node *newData = new Node;
    newData -> data = x;
    newData -> nextAddress = previous;
    previous -> nextAddress = newData;
}
```

Comment: Если не секрет... а на... ну в смысле, а зачем у вас вот тут `previous -> nextAddress = newData - 1;` единица вычитается?..

Comment: нечаянно её сюда вставил) вообще просто пытался играться с индексами для предыдущего, а так да, -1 следует убрать. (UPD, убрав -1 программа начала циклиться)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Так Вы же его "замкнули":

```
Node* newData = new Node;
newData->data = x;
newData->nextAddress = previous;
previous->nextAddress = newData;
```

У Вас следующий элемент за текущим это "предыдущий". Должно быть как-то так:

```
newData->nextAddress = previous->nextAddress;
```

Answer (score 2):

Ну вот смотрите сами - в функции `addAfter()` вы нашли элемент в списке, после которого нужно вставить новый. Это указатель `Node *previous`.
Далее создали новый элемент на указатель `Node *newData`.
А дальше вы зацикливаете список на последние 2 элемента, т.к. продолжение списка вы указываете на предыдущий элемент

```
newData->nextAddress = previous; // продолжение списка вы зацикливаете на предыдущий элемент
previous->nextAddress = newData;
```

Должно быть

```
newData->nextAddress = previous->nextAddress;
previous->nextAddress = newData;
```